# Mysqli prepared statement select not working

Tags: php, mysqli

What is wrong with this prepared statement? I cannot seem to get this to work.

```
$session = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['s']);

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT quantity FROM details WHERE session = ?");
$stmt->bind_param( "s", $session); 
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($quantity);
```

when I `echo $quantity;` the result just comes up with 0 when it should appear with a number between 1 and 10.

Comment: plz check: http://jp.php.net//manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: 1) Don't mix mysql and mysqli functions! 2) You're using parameterised queries, you do not need to and should not escape the value on top of that. It's either or, not both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT quantity FROM details WHERE session = ?");
$stmt->bind_param( "s", $session); 
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($quantity);
$stmt->fetch();

echo $quantity
```